# Sometimes my pc works slower but when I open task mannager is magicaly works well

Tags: performance, virus, malware

It's not an ugernt situation but still this problem annoys me. Sometimes if I leave the pc idle when I come back it works a bit slower and when I right click on the desktop to refresh it takes some time to load instead of happening instanly. I taught maybe it was a virus so i checked with avast Avg and Malwarebytes for any possible virus or harmful program yet I found nothing. I tried with CCleaner and well after I did the cleanup it was the same and then I taught maybe it was a concealed virus since I had that problem before so I opened the task mannager to see all the processes and I saw nothing suspicious only that the pc was working fine again and in the second I closed the task mannager it resumed to beeing slow. Ussualy a restart solves this but it's annoying when it happends and I think it might be a vrey well hidden virus but I don't know how to find it if that's the case.

Comment: There are a number of processes designed to take advantage of when the machine is idle so they don't compete for resources (malware checking, backup, updating, various housecleaning tasks, etc.).  If they are in the middle of a task when you go to use the machine again, it may take a short time for them to wrap up the task and safely stow things away again, so the system may seem slow temporarily.

Answer (score -1):

If you already checked for viruses, rebooted your system and searched for background processes you can check for needed updates and download new drivers. Delete temp files, maybe free some space on the hard drive. Scan your PC with anti-malware again, upgrade every app and maybe OS. Then reboot your PC again. Maybe it is an issue with hardware if these steps are not working for you